# ELF C++ Protection / Password

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering

I often to CTF's online @ root-me.org. Since a few weeks I try to work a bit on my reverse engineering skills. The challenges at root-me.org are ideal for this.

I have completed 5 of their crack challenges but cannot seem to work out how to get the password for the ELF C++ 0 Protection binary. I have no experience with C++ and reversed it looks even more unreadable for me.

They provide a paper to get more insight in how to start. But even that leaves me clueless. I see the routine (in ASM) that ends with a test al,al and makes the jump to either correct or incorrect password, but I cannot find the correct password nor can I find where the user entered password is stored.

Can any help me with this? Spend a lot of time figuring this out but clearly need some mentoring.

I use IDA Pro and/or gdb & objdump

https://www.root-me.org/en/Challenges/Cracking/ELF-C-0-protection (binary)

```
/* This file has been generated by the Hex-Rays decompiler.
Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Hex-Rays <info@hex-rays.com>

   Detected compiler: GNU C++
*/

#include <defs.h>


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function declarations

int init_proc();
// int __cxa_atexit(const char *, ...); weak
// int __cdecl std::string::operator+=(_DWORD, _DWORD); weak
// int __gmon_start__(void); weak
// int __cdecl std::string::operator[](_DWORD, _DWORD); weak
// _DWORD std::ios_base::Init::Init(std::ios_base::Init *this); idb
// _DWORD std::string::length(std::string *this); idb
// _DWORD __cdecl std::ios_base::Init::~Init(std::ios_base::Init *__hidden this); idb
// int __cdecl std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(_DWORD, _DWORD); weak
// _DWORD __cdecl std::string::~string(std::string *this); idb
// _DWORD __cdecl std::string::compare(std::string *this, const char *); idb
// int __cdecl std::string::string(_DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD); weak
// int __cdecl std::allocator<char>::~allocator(_DWORD); weak
// int std::ostream::operator<<(_DWORD, const char *, ...); weak
// int __cdecl std::allocator<char>::allocator(_DWORD); weak
void _x86_get_pc_thunk_bx();
signed int deregister_tm_clones();
int register_tm_clones();
signed int _do_global_dtors_aux();
int frame_dummy();
std::string *__stdcall plouf(std::string *a1, int a2, std::string *a3);
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp);
int __cdecl __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int a1, int a2);
int GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5ploufSsSs();
bool __cdecl std::operator==<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(std::string *a1, char *a2);
int _libc_csu_init();
void term_proc();

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Data declarations

// extern _UNKNOWN std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char>>; weak
_UNKNOWN unk_8048DB0; // weak
_UNKNOWN unk_8048DC4; // weak
_UNKNOWN unk_8048DCC; // weak
int (*_frame_dummy_init_array_entry[3])() = { &frame_dummy, &GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5ploufSsSs, &_do_global_dtors_aux }; // weak
int (*_do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry)() = &_do_global_dtors_aux; // weak
_UNKNOWN _dso_handle; // weak
_UNKNOWN std::cerr; // weak
_UNKNOWN std::cout; // weak
char completed_6591; // weak
_UNKNOWN std::__ioinit; // weak
// extern _UNKNOWN _gmon_start__; weak


//----- (08048738) --------------------------------------------------------
int init_proc()
{
  int result; // eax@1

  result = (int)&_gmon_start__;
  if ( &_gmon_start__ )
    result = __gmon_start__();
  return result;
}
// 8048790: using guessed type int __gmon_start__(void);

//----- (08048890) --------------------------------------------------------
#error "8048893: positive sp value has been found (funcsize=2)"

//----- (080488C0) --------------------------------------------------------
void _x86_get_pc_thunk_bx()
{
  ;
}

//----- (080488D0) --------------------------------------------------------
signed int deregister_tm_clones()
{
  return 3;
}
// 80488D0: could not find valid save-restore pair for ebp

//----- (08048900) --------------------------------------------------------
int register_tm_clones()
{
  return 0;
}
// 8048900: could not find valid save-restore pair for ebp

//----- (08048940) --------------------------------------------------------
signed int _do_global_dtors_aux()
{
  signed int result; // eax@2

  if ( !completed_6591 )
  {
    result = deregister_tm_clones();
    completed_6591 = 1;
  }
  return result;
}
// 8048940: could not find valid save-restore pair for ebp
// 804B18C: using guessed type char completed_6591;

//----- (08048960) --------------------------------------------------------
int frame_dummy()
{
  return register_tm_clones();
}
// 8048960: could not find valid save-restore pair for ebp

//----- (0804898D) --------------------------------------------------------
std::string *__stdcall plouf(std::string *a1, int a2, std::string *a3)
{
  int v3; // esi@2
  unsigned int v4; // ebx@2
  unsigned int v5; // eax@2
  int v6; // eax@2
  char v8; // [sp+1Bh] [bp-1Dh]@1
  unsigned int i; // [sp+1Ch] [bp-1Ch]@1

  std::allocator<char>::allocator(&v8);
  std::string::string(a1, &unk_8048DB0, &v8);
  std::allocator<char>::~allocator(&v8);
  for ( i = 0; *(_BYTE *)std::string::operator[](a2, i); ++i )
  {
    v3 = *(_BYTE *)std::string::operator[](a2, i);
    v4 = i;
    v5 = std::string::length(a3);
    v6 = std::string::operator[](a3, v4 % v5);
    std::string::operator+=(a1, (char)(v3 ^ *(_BYTE *)v6));
  }
  return a1;
}
// 8048780: using guessed type int __cdecl std::string::operator+=(_DWORD, _DWORD);
// 80487A0: using guessed type int __cdecl std::string::operator[](_DWORD, _DWORD);
// 8048820: using guessed type int __cdecl std::string::string(_DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD);
// 8048830: using guessed type int __cdecl std::allocator<char>::~allocator(_DWORD);
// 8048860: using guessed type int __cdecl std::allocator<char>::allocator(_DWORD);

//----- (08048A86) --------------------------------------------------------
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  const char *v3; // ebx@2
  int v4; // eax@2
  int v5; // eax@2
  int v6; // eax@2
  int v7; // ebx@2
  int v8; // eax@4
  int v9; // eax@4
  int v10; // eax@5
  char v12; // [sp+0h] [bp-16h]@3
  char v13; // [sp+1h] [bp-15h]@3
  char v14; // [sp+2h] [bp-14h]@3
  char v15; // [sp+6h] [bp-10h]@3
  char v16; // [sp+Ah] [bp-Ch]@3
  int *v17; // [sp+12h] [bp-4h]@1
  __int64 savedregs; // [sp+16h] [bp+0h]@3

  v17 = &argc;
  if ( argc > 1 )
  {
    std::allocator<char>::allocator(&v13);
    std::string::string(&v16, &unk_8048DC4, &v13);
    std::allocator<char>::allocator(&v12);
    std::string::string(&v15, &unk_8048DCC, &v12);
    plouf((std::string *)&v14, (int)&v15, (std::string *)&v16);
    std::string::~string((std::string *)&v15);
    std::allocator<char>::~allocator(&v12);
    std::string::~string((std::string *)&v16);
    std::allocator<char>::~allocator(&v13);
    LODWORD(savedregs) = argv[1];
    if ( std::operator==<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>((std::string *)&v14, (char *)savedregs) )
    {
      v8 = std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(&std::cout, "Bravo, tu peux valider en utilisant ce mot de passe...");
      std::ostream::operator<<(v8, (const char *)&std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char>>);
      v9 = std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(&std::cout, "Congratz. You can validate with this password...");
      std::ostream::operator<<(v9, (const char *)&std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char>>);
    }
    else
    {
      v10 = std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(&std::cout, "Password incorrect.");
      std::ostream::operator<<(v10, (const char *)&std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char>>);
    }
    v7 = 0;
    std::string::~string((std::string *)&v14);
  }
  else
  {
    v3 = *argv;
    v4 = std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(&std::cerr, "usage : ");
    v5 = std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(v4, v3);
    v6 = std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(v5, " password");
    std::ostream::operator<<(v6, (const char *)&std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char>>);
    v7 = 5;
  }
  return v7;
}
// 80487F0: using guessed type int __cdecl std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(_DWORD, _DWORD);
// 8048820: using guessed type int __cdecl std::string::string(_DWORD, _DWORD, _DWORD);
// 8048830: using guessed type int __cdecl std::allocator<char>::~allocator(_DWORD);
// 8048840: using guessed type int std::ostream::operator<<(_DWORD, const char *, ...);
// 8048860: using guessed type int __cdecl std::allocator<char>::allocator(_DWORD);

//----- (08048C9C) --------------------------------------------------------
int __cdecl __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int a1, int a2)
{
  int result; // eax@3

  if ( a1 == 1 && a2 == 0xFFFF )
  {
    std::ios_base::Init::Init((std::ios_base::Init *)&std::__ioinit);
    result = __cxa_atexit((const char *)std::ios_base::Init::~Init, &std::__ioinit, &_dso_handle);
  }
  return result;
}
// 8048770: using guessed type int __cxa_atexit(const char *, ...);

//----- (08048CDB) --------------------------------------------------------
int GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5ploufSsSs()
{
  return __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(1, 0xFFFF);
}

//----- (08048CF7) --------------------------------------------------------
bool __cdecl std::operator==<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(std::string *a1, char *a2)
{
  return std::string::compare(a1, a2) == 0;
}

//----- (08048D20) --------------------------------------------------------
int _libc_csu_init()
{
  int v0; // edi@1
  int result; // eax@1
  signed int v2; // esi@1

  v0 = 0;
  init_proc();
  result = (int)_frame_dummy_init_array_entry;
  v2 = &_do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry - _frame_dummy_init_array_entry;
  if ( v2 )
  {
    do
      result = _frame_dummy_init_array_entry[v0++]();
    while ( v0 != v2 );
  }
  return result;
}
// 804AEF4: using guessed type int (*_frame_dummy_init_array_entry[3])();
// 804AEFC: using guessed type int (*_do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry)();

//----- (08048D94) --------------------------------------------------------
void term_proc()
{
  ;
}

#error "There were 1 decompilation failure(s) on 14 function(s)"
```

Comment: That C code doesn't look like anything to be read or understand by a human. Problem description is not readable without login. `test al,al` will set zero flag when `al` is equal to zero. I guess correct password produces zero (like C `strcmp()`) So from there you have to backtrack, how the value in `al` is calculated. If you know x86 Assembly and have debugger and can run that binary, it should be easy. If you are missing some of that, then you will probably not solve that task.

Comment: I indented some code

Comment: Changing the code to C,C++ through some decompiler won't come in handy here, solving this challenge will require a debugger. <br> Try running the program and checking the stack at every step and **specifically** at the compare step.<br> The **C++** string is a complicated data type and all the operators are overloaded so it won't be clear.

Comment: This chall is not very hard though. After decompilation, you can see what the function "plouf" is doing. You can use a debugger, gdb will do the work.
Hint: Check for v14 in main function that will be changed due to function.